# ros offline install

Tags: ros, installation, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to install ros on a ubuntu machine which doesn't have access to the internet. I have another machine (windows) that can access the internet. I tried grabbing the svn from https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/trunk/ and figured out the steps for compiling and getting ros-core to work. Now the challenge I am facing is that each package I need obviously has dependencies that usually get downloaded via rosdep but now I have to do this manually, so I was wondering if there is a tar file with the basic packages i.e. what gets included in the desktop-full version of the ros install options? I'd appreciate any help on this.
Thanks,
JD

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10201/ros-offline-install/) by [scheme](https://answers.ros.org/users/664/scheme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-06-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there is a tar file containing all the external dependencies; however, it shouldn't be too hard to generate one yourself. As you have already pointed out, you can use `rosdep satisfy <packages>` to generate a list of required packages that have not been installed yet. (Or use `rosdep depdb <packages>` to get a list of all the packages, even those that have been installed.)

Now, you can use any of the usual [Ubuntu offline installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#line-204) methods to generate a list of packages on your Ubuntu machine, download them from the Windows machine and install them on Ubuntu. My favourite is [apt-offline](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scheme](https://answers.ros.org/users/664/scheme/) on 2011-06-10**:
Oh wow thanks Martin! I didn't know about apt-offline or the other methods like that. Been using ubuntu for many years and never had the need to install things offline until now. It didn't strike me that there would be such methods built into ubuntu. Thanks again. :)